# export multi artboard indesign file as multiple single PDFs

Tags: adobe-indesign

Ive got indesign 2017.1 as part of adobe CC.

Is it possible in the PDF export dialog to print a multi artboard indesign document as multiple 1 page files, rather than as a combined multi page PDF ?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with Acrobat, no need for anything third party. You merely can't do it with InDesign alone.

- Export your InDesign file as a multi page PDF.
- Open the PDF in Acrobat and choose `View > Tools > Pages` and click the `Extract` option.
  [image]
- Insert from page `1` to page `[last page]` and then tick `Extract Pages as separate files`, finally click `OK`.
- Navigate to a folder somewhere to save to.. and click `Save`.

Acrobat will split all pages to separate files into the folder you chose, leaving the original multi-page PDF in tact.

Comment: Thanks @scott , that was my plan B, my only concern was that the files are for print and wondered if running them through another programme may strip some print meta data / run some compression on the files

Comment: If you export as something like PDF/X-1a then the split files will still be PDF/X-1a compliant. The splitting doesn't reformat the PDF really. It merely deletes/extracts pages.

Answer (score 1):

No, not natively straight from InDesign.

This used to be possible by printing postscript files and then using Distiller, but this approach was abandoned by Adobe years ago in favour of the PDF export option, and the old tools have become unreliable since then. I'm not sure you can even install the generic postscript driver anymore.

Best option is a third party plugin or script of some type. I've used [Zevrix Output Factory](http://zevrix.com/outputfactory.php) for this kind of thing for years. It's not free, but worth the money if you regularly need a range of batch output options. There is a free trial if you just need a one-off solution.

Someone else may know of a script.